# How to overcome Cross Site Scripting vulnerability in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss, sql-injection

The part of the code am working on is vulnerable to stored XSS. Below is the code.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"     OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"    
        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"  OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_OnRowDeleting"  OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"  Width ="1000px" class="grid">


   <Columns>   

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name">   
            <ItemTemplate>   
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Uname") %>'></asp:Label>   
            </ItemTemplate>   
            <EditItemTemplate>   
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Uname") %>'></asp:TextBox>   //this is the line vulnerable to XSS
            </EditItemTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField>       </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code behind

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Uid,Uname,Utype,Uemail,ClientName,ProjectName,Ulog from usrtable where ClientName='" + clientname + "' and Utype='Admin' or ClientName='" + clientname + "'and Utype='Normal'", con);
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
    }  

 if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
```

Can you let me know where am going wrong. Is it on the client side where I am binding the column names to textbox in gridview?

Comment: As well as maybe XSS, it looks like you're wide open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) too.  Please spend some time reading about [how to prevent it](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I think if I use parameterized query I can avoid sql injection risk. I have read many documents and I came across this. But not sure of XSS for the above code. please guide me

Comment: How can I ask for more help here